# Is there is any way to iterate nested list and enter list values in a input form one by one?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

**Problem Facing:-** I have a page in which i have to input the data by reading excel and click on some btn. To achieve this i created a excel reader which fetch the data and strore in a list (Nested list if excel has multiple data set). If excel have single data set then my script is working fine but in case there is multiple set then scripts not behaving as expected. it iterating the first list values and perform some actions and close the browser and again launching the browser and doing the same stuff, which i don't want. I wants if excel reader return nested list then my script should perform set of actions repetively till last list values.
below are the step details.

I am reading data from excel using 'openpyxl'

**Step1 :-** Here is my 'excel reader' Utility:-

```
def fetchTestDataRowWise(worksheet_name, rowStartIndexDataStartReading, colFromWhereDataStartReading):
dataFilePath = "..//..//TestData1.xlsx"
workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(dataFilePath)
worksheet = workbook[worksheet_name]
rows = worksheet.max_row
cols = worksheet.max_column
# print(f"Total number of rows {rows} and Total Number of columns are {cols}")
dataList = []
for i in range(rowStartIndexDataStartReading, rows + 1):
    tempDataList = []
    for j in range(colFromWhereDataStartReading, cols + 1):
        data1 = worksheet.cell(i, j)
        data2 = data1.value
        if data2 is not None:
            tempDataList.append(data2)
    dataList.insert(i, tempDataList)
return dataList
```

**Step 2** Here is my Excel Data:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD04R.png)

**Step 3:-**
Excel reader returning list as :- [['840-9754', 28], ['840-9755', 29], ['840-9756', 30]]

**Step 4:-** Attached screenshot is my input form, in this input form i have to enter the values like first enter Item Nbr=840-9754 then Item Qty=28 and then Click on 'Add Sku' btn repeat this step for next list and after completing all list items click on 'Complete' btn.
[enter image description here][2]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD04R.png)

**Step 5:-** Here is my Conftest.py

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def setup(request):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(ConfigReader.readconfigdata('Details', 'app_url'))
    driver.maximize_window()
    request.cls.driver = driver
    yield
    driver.close()
```

**Step 6:-** this is my 'action' methods for above mentioned fields

```
    def enterItemNbr(self, enterSKU):
    itemNbr = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ConfigReader.readlocator('locators', 'itemNbrInputBox'))
    itemNbr.click()
    itemNbr.send_keys(enterSKU)

def enterItemQty(self, qty):
    itemQTY = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ConfigReader.readlocator('locators', 'itemQtyInputBox'))
    itemQTY.click()
    itemQTY.clear()
    itemQTY.send_keys(qty)

def clickAddSKU(self):
    addSKUBtn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ConfigReader.readlocator('locators', 'addSKUBtn'))
    addSKUBtn.click()

def AddSKU(self, enterSKU, enterQty):
    self.enterItemNbr(enterSKU)
    self.enterItemQty(enterQty)
    self.clickAddSKU()
```

**Step 7:-** Here is my Test Case

class TestMaterialPerformCycleCount(BaseClass):

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize('data', BaseClass.fetchTestDataRowWise("CycleCountTestData", 2, 1))
def test_PerformCycleCount(self, data):
    userLogin = Login(self.driver)
    userLogin.login()

    performCycleCount = MaterialPerformCycleCount(self.driver)
    performCycleCount.enterItemNbr(data[1])
    time.sleep(2)
    performCycleCount.enterItemQty(int(data[2]))
    time.sleep(2)
    performCycleCount.clickAddSKUbtn()
```

**Note:-** if i change the fixture scope then i am not achieving the objective for other test cases.

Comment: Too much code. Too much text. You can do repetetive things by using loops. You can find out if you have nested lists using conditions and isinstance(). You seem to have solved reading excel - why put it inside here? You get `[['840-9754', 28], ['840-9755', 29], ['840-9756', 30]]` - why do you need to input that at all (and where) - you got lists you can simply iterate the list and use the values.

Comment: Thanx Patrick, This is for better clarity. I tried this way you mentioned here but didn't get the required results.